# How to send HTTP POST request and receive response?

Tags: android

I'm going to create mobile application that works with CommuniGate Pro server.

For example, I need to make the following Android Client `C` - CGP Server `S` conversation and get `XIMSS.nonce` node value:

```
C:GET /ximsslogin/ HTTP/1.1
  Host: myserver.com
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Content-Length: 42

  <XIMSS><listFeatures id="list" /><XIMSS>

S:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Length: 231
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
  Server: CommuniGatePro/5.3

  <XIMSS><nonce>2C3E575E5498CE63574D40F18D00C873</nonce><language>german</language><response id="s"/></XIMSS>
```

Example, in ActionScript 3.0 it looks this way:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(...);
urlRequest.method = ...;
urlRequest.data = ...;
loader.load(urlRequest);

private function completeHandler(...):void { ... };
```

How will it look in Java for **Android 2.1**?

Comment: I believe you're going to need to elaborate more in order to get any meaningful assistance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Schnapple says your question seems very broad and is confusing to read and understand.

Here is some general code to send a HTTP POST and get a response from a server though that may be helpful.

---

```
public String postPage(String url, File data, boolean returnAddr) {

    ret = null;

    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);

    httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    response = null;

    FileEntity tmp = null;       

    tmp = new FileEntity(data,"UTF-8");

    httpPost.setEntity(tmp);

    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        System.out.println("HTTPHelp : ClientProtocolException : "+e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("HTTPHelp : IOException : "+e);
    } 
            ret = response.getStatusLine().toString();

            return ret;
}
```

Comment: When i used this method the response i got from my server is "Image not provided". How to solve this?