# how to attach image to upload in android?

Tags: android

I want to select an image from an android image gallery and upload it to a web server

Can any one guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?p=490

image uploading + parameters

only parameters + text

very simple but effective class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice upload code sample. It uploads a file - exactly what you need [How to send HTTP POST request and receive response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038409/how-to-send-http-post-request-and-recieve-response/3038747#3038747).

Comment: example you provided not complete enough to understand or implement.