# Storing data from client desktop application to server DB

Tags: php, c++, mysql, sqlite, http

What is the best way to send bulk data periodically from a SQLite db present in desktop application to DB in MySQL server through a PHP script. I want to send the maximum possible amount of data to the server at one-shot and I want to reduce the number of pings to the server. The desktop application is implemented in C++ with MFC.

I tried implementing a basic module and got this problem:

The CString variable used to store the string content is not storing more than 10,000 characters is there a bigger data structure to store more amount of content.

It would be helpful, if you can suggest me on the below areas :

1. Is there any maximum amount of data that could be sent using http.
2. Is there any other protocols by which data could be sent to the php script in server.
3. Best format for data transfer.

Please also let me know, if there are any other things to consider to build a good software system for this task.

I already have a system in place to send few amount of information (about 5 kb) every 30 secs. The problem is it results in huge number of server pings from multiple clients. Hence I would like to send data in bulk after storing them locally in sqllite3 db.

Comment: Through a PHP script? Are both DBs on the same machine?

Comment: best format has to be json i guess

Comment: No there are no such limitation by-design in http protocol on maximum amount of data that could be sent. Only timeouts on concrete servers.

Comment: And for your database transfer please refer previous discussion of Stackoverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679291/how-to-transfer-sqlite-db-to-web-server-on-android-phone-android

Comment: @nemasu : The sqllite db remains on the client end of the system at multiple locations, the data has to be transferred from there to the MySQL db in server through php scripts.

Comment: @HiteshVaghani Whilst there is no limit imposed by the http protocol, there is a maximum size php will accept assuming the data is posted to the server then check the value for post_max_size and upload_max_filesize