# Uploading an image using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android

I am trying to upload an image from my device file system to a server. The upload works fine when i use a **WIFI** connection, but fails when on **GPRS**. My code is as below:

```
String request=null;
byte[] attachmentData;
//read the image from the file system
attachmentData=bytesReadfromthefilesystem; 
//I use Apache's Base64 encoding to convert the byte array to string    
 request=Base64.encode(data);

  URL url = new URL(
        "http://mydomain.com:9090//abc/http?ID=12345");
        HttpURLConnection  httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "text/plain");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
    httpURLConnection.connect();
    OutputStream outStream outStream =httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
    if (outStream != null) {
            if (request.getData().length() > 0) {
                outStream.write(request.getBytes());
            }

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            outStream = null;      
      }
```

The image size is close to 1MB. I am trying on Samsung Galaxy Pop (Android 2.2.1). I do not get any errors too. Am i missing out on something here? Could someone kindly help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "upload fails" :)

Comment: The image does not reach the server i try to upload to. :)

Answer (score 1):

did you set the permission on your AndroidManifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to `setConnectionTimeout()` to 300000 (5 minutes) or something like that.

Comment: I have set the time out to 5 minutes but still seems to be the same. Is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: You should try to make a MultiPartPost. Check this SO [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038409/how-to-send-http-post-request-and-recieve-response/3038747#3038747) of how to do this.

Comment: Using a small image around 200 Kb gets uploaded using GPRS

Comment: It must be the connection then... maybe you lose your connection or something like that. Check if you get any answer from the connection... I'm not sure how you can do that using your techique.