# Upload large files on the web server on android

Tags: android, upload

I want to upload files on a web server in my android app.Currently i am able to upload files around 5mb from the device but more than this gives a outofmemory exception and also makes app very unstable.

i am looking for a method using which we can upload the data in the app background plus of bigger size. Any tutorials/ code is highly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi mudit  how to send an image to webserver having 2mb .can you send me some example code. I'm working in 2.3.3Api

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599305/android-outofmemoryerror-while-uploading-video-how-best-to-chunk/3206047#3206047) post from [Fedor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95313/fedor).

The main point is that you need to set on chunking.

e.g.

```
 connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(chunkSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

This GitHub library could help :
https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service  2.3K stars Apr 2020

[image]

"
-Easily upload files (Multipart/Binary/FTP out of the box) in the background with progress indication notification

-upload files to a server with FTP, HTTP multipart/form-data or binary requests

-handle multiple concurrent uploads in the background, even if the device is idle (Doze mode)

-automatically retry failed uploads, with a configurable exponential backoff
possibility to automatically delete uploaded files when the upload is successful

**Apps and libraries powered by this library-**

-JIRA Cloud

-Quora

...

"