# Posting large video file on Facebook from android

Tags: android, facebook, file, video

Hi am trying to post video file on Facebook from my android application, I am able to post 5MB file successfully but when I am trying to post large file say 95MB **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** brokes out. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk) link to post the video.

Is there any other methods to post the video file on Facebook. Please help me to resolved this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible. but it will take time based on your video file size. Please refer this answer to post video file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151708/upload-video-to-facebook-in-android/12470730#12470730

Answer (score 1):

Your video filesize is probably larger than the amount of free memory allocated on your device.  Considering that you said you were trying to upload a 95MB file on your smartphone, that is too large to hold in a `byte[]`.

I found [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599305/android-outofmemoryerror-while-uploading-video-how-best-to-chunk) online that allows you to upload chunks of data at a time to prevent OOM exceptions, but AFAIK our Facebook Android SDK doesn't have that sort of option available.  Your best bet is to either compress/scale the video to a more acceptable size, or write your own method to POST a video to Facebook in chunks.