# How can I reduce the video recording size in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, camera, flutter, video-processing

I'm using flutter [camera plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera) to record the video. But the recorded video size is too big. Something around 20mb for 1 min. How can I reduce the size (one of which is how to reduce resolution)? Also I have changed my VideoEncodingBitRate to `3000000`. Like this `mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);`.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the size, you can employ any or both of these 2 methods:

## Resolution

You can see them in the example
`controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);`, change this to `ResolutionPreset.low` or some other customer value (does not have to be `preset`)

## Encoding

You can use different encoding algorithms, such as FFmpeg using this plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_ffmpeg. See also this question and its answers [how to reduce size of video before upload to server programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263797/how-to-reduce-size-of-video-before-upload-to-server-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: ResolutionPreset.high, ResolutionPreset.medium and ResolutionPreset.low is giving me the video of the same size. In all the 3 option I'm getting video size around 21 MB.