# Fast Video Streaming and Upload Android

Tags: android, performance, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, video-streaming

Fast Streaming & Uploading Videos On Mobile Apps with AWS S3

Im developing a app witch has Android, iOS Clients were users can upload videos and photos and view as news feed. I store my video file on Amazone s3. Video length is limited to 30sec.

When user is uploading 30 sec video from their gallery there are some high quality videos witch is even exceed 100MB so those video files take ages to upload. So i tried to convert them before upload using ffmpeg-android library but it also take almost same amount of time to convert the file so it seems this solution also point less. (convert in the scene reducing the video resolution and frame rate)

Im using ExoPlayer to play videos

Note : Videos uploading from iOS are not that huge files.

**I want videos to upload fast and stream fast. Its big help if anyone can share their thoughts on this.**

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to do that:

1. Encode it to a lower bit rate and/or lower resolution. Have a look here: [Is it possible to compress video on Android?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991863/is-it-possible-to-compress-video-on-android)
2. Try to zip/compress it. Have a look here: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29

Unfortunately I never tried to do that with a 100MB video. This is why I suggested to you the first library (FFmpeg 4 Android).

Have a look on this discussion:

[Android: OutOfMemoryError while uploading video - how best to chunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599305/android-outofmemoryerror-while-uploading-video-how-best-to-chunk/3206047#3206047)

Comment: Hey @user2321465, Latest devices such as s5, nexus 5x if record a video with HDR enable 30sec it will be over 100MB. I tried to lower bit rate and resolution and bring it down to around 10MB but it take lot of time to convert  using FFmpeg 4 Android